# Не запускается отладчик QT Creator на macOS Catalina

Tags: qt, macos, отладка

Делаю проекты с интерфейсом в Qt Creator (последняя на данный момент версия) и все запускается/работает отлично. Но, как доходит до отладки, то отладчик просто уходит в бесконечный запуск и не начинает отладку. Использую macOS Catalina. Может, кто сталкивался с таким?